# Criteria for Pointwise Convergence of Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

There are many criteria for uniform convergence of continuous functions, such as Stone-Weirestrass etc... However are there any known results guaranteing that a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ in $C(R)$ converges pointwise to some discontinuous function?

Comment: If you don't care about the continuity of a limit function, then it's always true, just define $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$.

Comment: @Hasek That limit may not exist.

Comment: What is $R$? $\mathbb{R}$ or an arbitrary metric space? or...?

Comment: If $f_n \in C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, it can be shown, using Baire's Category Theorem, that such a pointwise limit must be continuous, except possibly at a meager set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A point-wise limit of a sequence of continuous real-valued functions is commonly called a Baire-1 function.

Some related results:

1.If $X$ is a metric space and $f:X\to \Bbb R$ is a Baire-1 function then the set of points of discontinuity of $f$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ set in X.

2.If $X$ is a metric space with no isolated points and $Y$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ subset of $X$ then there is a Baire-1 function $f:X\to \Bbb R$ with $f^{-1}\{0\}=X\setminus Y$ and such that $Y$ is the set of points of discontinuity of $f$.

3. If $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a Baire-1 function then every $f^{-1}\{y\}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set in $\Bbb R$ and $f^{-1}U$ is  $F_{\sigma \delta}$ in $\Bbb R$ for every open $U\subset \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

Generally we can use well known fact, that for convergence, for fixed $x$, $f_n(x)$ should be  [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence)

For exact condition which gives continuity for sequence continuous functions limit let's consider introduced by C.Arzela so called quasiuniform convergence:
We say, that on some $[a,b]$ segment sequence of continuous functions $f_n(x)$ quasiuniformly converged to continuous function $f(x)$, if for any $\forall \epsilon$ and any $N$ segment $[a,b]$ can be covered by finite amount intervals $(a_1,b_1),(a_1,b_1), \cdots, (a_i,b_i), \cdots, (a_k,b_k)$ and they can be assigned to numbers $n_1,n_2, \cdots, n_i, \cdots, n_k$ $(>N)$ that for every $x$ from $(a_i,b_i)$ performed simultaneously $|f(x)-f_{n_i}(x)|< \epsilon$.

Now using this concept Arzela proved theorem:

Suppose sequence of continuous functions $f_n(x)$ pointwise converged on $[a,b]$ segment to function $f(x)$. Then for $f(x)$ continuity is necessary and sufficient, that $f_n(x)$ converged quasiuniformly.

Comment: OP wants a sufficient condition for pointwise convergence to a function that is not continuous, not just convergence.

Comment: @RRL. Thanks for push. Hope now it looks more adequate.

Comment: That's really good.

Comment: This addresses the actual question directly and should have been accepted.

Comment: @RRL. Thanks. I think same, but who care?

Comment: Good attitude!!

Answer (score 2):

Given $f_n \in C(\mathbb{R})$ converging pointwise to $f$, **non-uniform convergence is** **necessary** for   $f \not\in C(\mathbb{R})$ and  uniform  convergence is sufficient for $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$.

However, **non-uniform convergence  is not sufficient** for the limit function to be discontinuous. For example, with $f_n(x) = n|x| e^{-n|x|}$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x$, and the convergence is not uniform since $f_n(1/n) = 1 \not\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

---

Another somewhat related fact is while the pointwise limit of a sequence continuous functions may be discontinuous, the points of discontinuity must form a nowhere dense set.